# prove the identity of the kronecker product of four matrix

Tags: matrices

Suppose that $H_i$($i=1,2,3,4$) are four arbitrary matrices, the Kronecker product relation below
$$
(H_1\otimes H_2)\otimes(H_3\otimes H_4)=H_1\otimes (H_2\otimes H_3)\otimes H_4
$$
holds due to the fact that $(H_1\otimes H_2)\otimes H_3=H_1\otimes (H_2\otimes H_3)$. But how can we prove it directly?

Comment: Just FYI: the plural of matrix is "matrices"

Comment: @TerrenceTown: Tks a lot.

Comment: To prove associativity, simply verify the equality entrywise.